# Unity XR Ray / Line renderer on the floor

Tags: unity, virtual-reality, controllers

When using Unity's XR system, the teleport ray / line renderer I'm stuck on the floor. Turning the XR rig also turns the line, so the line is stuck on 0,0,0 on the XR Rig

I've played with most settings but can't find why the line isn't being translated to the action based controllers position. Using `Debug.Log` shows the action based position from the controller is correct.

I'm following [LevelUp's tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wGvh7Suo1h4) on how to create a grab and teleport manager to enable having several action based XR controllers at once.

Disabling the other XR Controller (Action-Based) controllers seems to resolve the issue but I need them enabled to be able to teleport and grab with the same controller.

Has anyone else had this issue? Any tips on troubleshooting or reasons for why this would happen?

[image: Unity Inspector and XRI input actions]

[image: Several components]

[image: Line Renderer component]

Comment: Can you show us the configuration of your LineRenderer component?

Comment: @DMGregory added image showing Line Renderer

Comment: I note that the "use world space" box is ticked. Do you get different results when unticking the box?